# How can I group Test steps in Allure report

Tags: selenium-webdriver, allure

I am looking for solution where I can group test steps in allure report.

Currently what is happening :

For example I have one test case login where there are 5 steps `i.e go to login page, enter login detail, click on submit etc.` But in allure report I want to show only 1 steps for all 5 login actions. is it possible?

So basically I want to display test case as steps and not scenarios as steps in report.

I searched a lot but did not find a way to do this with allure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call the functions inside `allure.step` block

```
@pytest.mark.sanity
class TestExample:

    def test_example(self):
        with allure.step('Do Login'):
            self.go_to_login_page()
            self.insert_user_name()
            self.insert_password()

    def go_to_login_page(self):
        Report.report_step('go to login page')

    def insert_user_name(self):
        Report.report_step('insert username')

    def insert_password(self):
        Report.report_step('insert password')
```

Or with page object

```
@pytest.mark.sanity
class TestExampleTest:

    def test_example(self):
        with allure.step('Do Login'):
            (LoginPage()
             .go_to_login_page()
             .insert_user_name()
             .insert_password())


class LoginPage:

    def go_to_login_page(self):
        Report.report_step('go to login page')
        return self

    def insert_user_name(self):
        Report.report_step('insert username')
        return self

    def insert_password(self):
        Report.report_step('insert password')
        return self
```

`report_step` is a static function in `Report.py` file

```
def report_step(step_title):
    with allure.step(step_title):
        pass
```

The steps will be grouped inside `'Do Login'` step

[image]

[image]

**Edit** Same idea with Java

```
public class Test {
    public void testMethod() {
        doLogin();
    }

    @Step("Do Login")
    public void doLogin() {
        new LoginPage()
                .goToLoginPage()
                .insertUserName("NAME")
                .insertPassword("PASSWORD");
    }
}

public class LoginPage {

    @Step("Go to login page")
    public LoginPage goToLoginPage() {
       step("goToLoginPage");
       return this;
    }

    @Step("Insert user name {userName}")
    public LoginPage insertUserName(String userName) {
       return this;
    }

    @Step("Insert password {password}")
    public LoginPage insertPassword(String password) {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help but I am using java :(

Comment: @HelpingHands I added the logic in Java, didn't test it though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will testing it asap and let you know.

Comment: I am error while import this : import static io.qameta.allure.Allure.step;
I am adding in my test class. Do I need any special dependency for same? I have already allure report running fine so I don't think I am missing any dependency.

Comment: @HelpingHands Add `io.qameta.allure` to pom. You can see examples [here](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/)

Comment: Getting this error : https://prnt.sc/mzbiec, I am using exact your given syntax. Do I need to return something?

Comment: @Guy- can you please look at above screenshot?

Comment: @HelpingHands What if you use `step` as annotation? `@Step("Insert userName {userName})
    public LoginPage insertUserName(String userName) {
       return this;
    }`

Comment: @Guy- For annotation generally I use `@Step` with capital S, do you want me to use `@step`? i.e start with small s?

Comment: @HelpingHands Step, with capital S

Comment: @Guy- if I use @step, It says : `Lambda expression not expected here`, Screenshot : https://prnt.sc/n00qau

Comment: I meant use step as an annotation. Added example to the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190310/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-guy).